# Java: About Recursive counting

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having some problems whit an exercise I found.

I was provided a method, and can't make any changes to it.

Inside said method, I should identify the first repeating digit, beetwen two integers, And return it's position.

For example: 1234 and 4231 results in 1.

And I managed to make it work,

It's just that it doesn't work if I try to use the method more than once, it simply keeps adding to the previous value.

This is my code so far

```
public static final int BASENUMERACAO = 10;
public static int indice = 0;
private static int getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b) {
    if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both numbers should positive " + a + " " + b);
    } else {
        if (a % BASENUMERACAO == b % BASENUMERACAO) {
            return indice;
        } else if (a / BASENUMERACAO != 0 && b / BASENUMERACAO != 0) {
            indice++;
            return getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(a / BASENUMERACAO, b / BASENUMERACAO);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I tried passing index, as a local variavel, but it just overrides the curent value, everytime it's called, therefore only returning 0 or -1

Could someone tell me how to I do keep count in a recursive method, or just how do I identify the digit whitout a counter?

Comment: Hint: `indice` is static.

Answer (score 0):

Create another method to call your recursive method and use the vars that you need as parameter for the recursive version and keep passing them.

Something like:

```
private static int myMethod( int a, int b ) {
    return myRecursiveMethod( a, b, 0, 0 );
}

private static int myRecursiveMethod( int a, int b, int var1, int var2 ) {
    // do the recursive work...
    myRecursiveMethod( newValueForA, newValueForB, var1, var2 ) {
}
```

Comment: Just tried something like that, It worked. Thank you very much. 

It seems like that is a neat little trick to know. 

The solution if interested: https://pastebin.com/cpv2Fvjf

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are retaining state from the previous invocation, in the `indice` variable. `indice` is an example of mutable global state, which is generally a bad idea for the reason you are experiencing here: you might carry over the results of previous calculations into new calculations, leading to unpredictable (or maybe unexpected) results.

Make your `indice` variable a parameter of the method:

```
private static int getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b, int indice) {
  // ...
}
```

So your recursive call will also pass a value for this:

```
return getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(a / BASENUMERACAO, b / BASENUMERACAO, indice);
```

To start the iteration, you can either explicitly pass 0, or you can create a method which takes just a and b:

```
private static int getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(int a, int b) {
  return getLowestIndexWithSameDigit(a, b, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it truly helped me a lot. That is a very nice trick to know. 

Solution if interested: https://pastebin.com/cpv2Fvjf